# How to find out object's location coordinates?

Tags: properties, coordinates

For example I have a cube and I moved it to a certain location.
I want to know if there is a way to find object's **global location**, so later I would be able to insert this location coordinates to another object.

[image]

***So my Question is: Is there a way I can see the location of a certain object and if yes how can I insert this location coordinates to another object ?***

Comment: in the transform tab in the properties panel (in edit mode) you can select global or local (for each vertex point or the whole object), and then you can copy it in object mode to an other object

Comment: For multiple objects might be better to enable copy attributes add-on: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Copy_Attributes_Menu